# removing random white space inside the top of a table

Tags: html, wordpress, jquery-jtable

I had to copy a table to place in WordPress and cannot figure out why the layout of the text in the columns does not immediately go to the top of the column (as you'd expect for the start of any new table).  I am providing the code as well as the actual url.  The live Wordpress url is: http://www.debralmorrison.com/about-debra-morrison/

The code is:

```
<h1>Debra Morrison, Financial Planner, Author, Speaker, &amp; Grief Coach</h1>
<table border="0" align="center"><tbody><tr>
<td style="width: 345px; padding-right: 20px;">
<p style="text-align: justify;"><img class="alignright size-full wp-image-2470" alt="Ms Morrison Growing Up" src="http://msmorrisonspeaks.com/wp-content/uploads/MsMorrisonGrowingUp.jpg" width="146" height="200" />Successful now, it was not always that way. Debra came from very humble beginnings. She grew up on a farm and worked 3 jobs to put herself through college. Debra is completely self-made always having supported herself with no providing partner or rich parents.</p>
<p style="text-align: justify;">A life-long student, Debra has trained with International Experts on Real Estate, Psychology, Public Speaking, Money Management, Fear-Busting, NeuroLinguist Programming &amp; Behavioral Finance, positioning herself alongside thought-leaders, politicians, comedians &amp; sports legends.</p>
&nbsp;
<img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-2545" title="Ms Morrison Speaks" src="http://msmorrisonspeaks.com/wp-content/uploads/row-1.jpg" alt="Ms Morrison Speaks" width="335" height="128" />
<p style="text-align: center;"><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-2549" title="Ms Morrison Speaks Money" src="http://msmorrisonspeaks.com/wp-content/uploads/row-2_1.jpg" alt="Ms Morrison Speaks Money" width="335" height="126" /></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-2550" title="Ms Morrison Speaks Money" src="http://msmorrisonspeaks.com/wp-content/uploads/row-3_1.jpg" alt="Ms Morrison Speaks Money" width="335" height="125" /></p>
<p style="text-align: justify;"><strong>From top left to top right:</strong></p>
<p style="text-align: justify;"><strong>Muriel Seibert,</strong> 1st Woman to Own Seat on NY Stock Exchange.
<strong>Kathy Whitlock</strong>, Winningest golfer on either LPGA or PGA—88 titles.
<strong>Loral Langemeier</strong>, Millionaire Maker
<strong>Michele Obama</strong>, First Lady of US
<strong>Ellie Smeal</strong>, Former President of NOW
<strong>Hillary Clinton</strong>, 67th US Secretary of State
<strong>Condoleezza Rice</strong>, 66th US Secretary of State
<strong>Allan Simpson &amp; Erskine Bowles</strong>, Former CO US Senator &amp; Former White House Chief of Staff, authored Simpson-Bowles/Nat’l Commission on Fiscal Responsibility &amp; Reform.</p>

<h3 style="text-align: justify;">Author, Int'l Motivational Speaker, Grief Coach</h3>
<p style="text-align: justify;">Debra has authored 3 books, <em>Common Sense Money Guide For Women, </em>and<em> New Widow Financial Lifeline.</em> She is also a Grief Coach and an International Motivational Speaker.</p>
<p style="text-align: justify;">Debra is driven by the desire to share financial nuggets that help women feel empowered about their finances &amp; their lives, regardless of circumstances.</p>
<p style="text-align: justify;">"I'm passionate about connecting, learning and teaching!"</p>
</td>
<td style="width: 345px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: opx;"><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/59993639" width="300" height="169" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
<p style="text-align: justify;"><strong>DEBRA L. MORRISON</strong> is a Fee-Only Wealth Manager who brings 36+ years of experience in personal financial planning and asset management. She received her Bachelor of Science in Business Administration from Messiah College, and earned both her Certified Financial Planner® designation and her Masters of Science in Retirement Planning from the College for Financial Planning. She has helped thousands of clients face and conquer their fears and attain financial security.</p>
<p style="text-align: justify;">What sets Debra apart is her caring and personalized service; she provided a full year's worth of pro bono financial planning and investment service for seven widows, one widower, and one orphan who lost their breadwinner/parent in the 9/11 tragedy. Debra cares about her clients-and has a vested interest in their happiness and fulfillment in life.</p>

<h3 style="text-align: justify;">Awards</h3>
<ul style="text-align: justify;">
    <li>1982 Passaic-Bergen Life Underwriter of the Year</li>
    <li>2011 Leading Woman Entrepreneur &amp; Business Owner of NJ</li>
    <li>2008 New Jersey's Best 50 Women in Business</li>
    <li>2008 WFNJ Extraordinary Woman in Finance</li>
    <li>2012 Grief Coach Academy Coach of the Year</li>
</ul>
<p style="text-align: justify;">She is listed in Marquis' <em>Who's Who in Finance
&amp; Industry &amp; Who's Who of American Women</em>
as well as <em>Nationwide Register's Who's Who in
Executives and Business</em>.</p>

<h3 style="text-align: justify;">Service</h3>
<ul style="text-align: justify;">
    <li>Adjunct Professor-Fairleigh Dickenson Univ,NJ</li>
    <li>Past Pres-Passaic-Bergen Life Underwriters Ass’n,</li>
    <li>Philharmonic Orchestra of NJ-Past Board Member</li>
    <li>Past Pres-Estate Planner Council of Bergen County,</li>
    <li>Past Treasurer-<a title="Kirkridge Retreat Center Board Member" href="http://kirkridge.org" target="_blank">Kirkridge Retreat Center</a>.</li>
</ul>
<p style="text-align: justify;">Ms. Morrison volunteers for Special Olympics and Habitat for Humanity &amp; enjoys skiing, golf, tennis, and scuba diving in her spare time.</p>

<h3 style="text-align: justify;">Press</h3>
<p style="text-align: justify;">Myriad media sources tap Debra’s wealth of experience. She has been featured on CNN, ABC, MSG’s Metro Money and CNNfn, as well as being quoted in The Wall Street Journal, USA Today, Nation’s Business, Ladies Home Journal, New York Times, Business Week, Family Money, Garden State Woman, Investment News, Dermatology Business Management, Journal of Financial Planning, Money, CNN Money, Financial Advisor, America Online's Moneywise, The Star Ledger and Reader’s Digest.</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the below CSS in your `stylesheet.css` or `style.css`

```
#post-2 > table > tbody > tr > td {vertical-align: top;}
```

or:

```
#post-2 > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) {vertical-align: top;}
```

**Solution 2:**

Set `vertical-align: top;` to `<td style="vertical-align: top;">`

```
<h1>Debra Morrison, Financial Planner, Author, Speaker, &amp; Grief Coach</h1>
<table border="0" align="center"><tbody><tr>
<td style="width: 345px; padding-right: 20px; vertical-align: top;">
....
```